# How do I write the constructor function that sets the size of a vector which is the attribute of my class in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

The attribute of my class is a vector whose size represents the number of dimensions of a vector. I have to write a constructor that makes a null vector for a given size. I'm not sure how to do it, this is what I've tried:

```
Vecteur(size_t d)
    : coord.size(d) { for( auto c : coord){ c = 0;}}
```

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Please include code as text, not as images.

Comment: All questions here must have all relevant information ***in the question itself as plain text***. Links can stop working at any time making questions meaningless. Code, data, or errors, shown as images cannot be copy/pasted; or edited or compiled for further research and investigation. This question must be [edit]ed, and all links and images removed and replaced with all relevant information, as plain text. All code must meet all requirements of a [mre]. You can find many other questions here that explain everything in plain text. There's no reason why this one can't, either.

Comment: Look into using a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Your can't initialize a member of your class member in using initializer list but you can only use constructors .

So your declare a constructor for your vector which initializes its member to zero then use this constructor in your class initializer list

Comment: The first sentence is jumbled. I'm not sure what you are trying to say there. I strongly recommend  rewording it. That said, if you're saying what I think you're saying, this doesn't answer the question.